# How to import mathjs module in Nodejs using ES6 Module syntax?

Tags: node.js, mathjs

The following works for me:

```
import { zeros } from "mathjs";
const w = zeros(5, 5);
```

but I'm trying to do something like: math.zeros(5, 5) as what I saw in the documentation https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/zeros.html
which will allow me to use math to access a lot of functions such us math.matrix(), math.square(array) ...etc.
But when I try to do the following:

```
import { math } from "mathjs";
const w = math.zeros(5, 5);
```

I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'mathjs' does not provide an export named 'math'
```

my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  . . .
  "type": "module",
  . . .
  "dependencies": {
    "mathjs": "^11.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `import * as math ...`? Or if it's the default export, just `import math ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [MDN: import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#description)

```
import { zero } from "mathjs"; // it's a name import
```

with importing zero like that you get only access to the 'zero' method

Try using

```
import math from 'mathjs' // it's a default import of math
const w = math.zeros(5, 5);
```

By importing math like that you get access to all its methods

Answer (score 0):

trying to use:

```
import math from 'mathjs' // it's a default import of math
const w = math.zeros(5, 5);
```

didn't work for me either. What worked is the following:

```
import * as math from "mathjs";
```

as suggested by jonrsharpe.